# Netmiko OSError: Search pattern never detected in send_command_expect: Destination

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, netmiko

I'm stuck here for more than an hour but seem like not able to find the solution for my issue. Issue is that I'm not able to completely match the string output.

**Actual output:**

```
hostname#$192.168.1.1/out/c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E3.bin flash:c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E3.bin
Destination filename [c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E3.bin]?
```

my code not working:

```
commandsend = "copy ftp://206.112.194.143/out/c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E3.bin flash:c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E3.bin"
output = connection.send_command(commandsend,expect_string=r'Destination filename')
output += connection.send_command('\n',expect_string=r'#')
```

copy ftp://x.x.x.x/out/c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E3.bin flash:c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E3.bin
21:11:27.067 GMT Wed May 12 2021
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./svu.py", line 292, in
output = uploading_update(models,ver[0],ver[1],ver[2],ver[3]) # Send to func {'CSR1000V': ['12.2.55',
File "./svu.py", line 119, in uploading_update
output = connection.send_command(commandsend,expect_string=r'Destination filename')
File "/home/repos/public/Python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 1112, in send_command
search_pattern))
OSError: Search pattern never detected in send_command_expect: Destination filename

I tried using the following but it still not working

```
output = connection.send_command(commandsend,expect_string=r'Destination.*')
output = connection.send_command(commandsend,expect_string='Destination.*')
output = connection.send_command(commandsend,expect_string=r'Destination filename.+')
```

I even tried adjusting the delay factor and fast_cli=False but still the same.

When I tried using the exact output. I'm seeing the below error.

```
output = connection.send_command(commandsend,expect_string=r'Destination filename [c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E3.bin]? ')
```

bad character range x-u at position 27

I this a Bug or something? Any missing option I need to use?

Comment: Did you set `ip ftp source-interface <interface>` on the device?

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your `expect_string=r'Destination filename [c2960x-universalk9-mz.152-7.E3.bin]? '` is, that Netmiko interprets the `expect_string` parameter as a [Regular Expression (regex)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) string, therefore what's inside the `[` and `]` brackets are treated as a range of characters you're trying to match, that's where the error comes from.
In your case, you want to match the exact `[` and `]` characters, so you need to escape them using `\` in 'raw' strings or `\\` in 'normal' strings. The same applies to `?` and `.` characters, which have special meaning in regex.

Therefore the right command would be:

```py
output = connection.send_command(commandsend,expect_string=r'Destination filename \[c2960x-universalk9-mz\.152-7\.E3\.bin\]\? ')
```

You can use online regex tools such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to help you build and test your regexes.

Also, if you are dealing with Cisco, I think you should look at `file prompt quiet` command, which disables these kinds of prompts.